# How to get GDAL to work with Google GCLOUD

Tags: python, django, gcloud, geodjango

I am getting the below error trying to deploy my app to gcloud app engine.
The whole problem is from trying to add the GDAL library to my app.

> File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/**init**.py", line 377, in
> **getattr**
> func = self.**getitem**(name)   File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/**init**.py", line 382, in
> **getitem**
> func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self)) AttributeError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64

I followed all the directions I could possibly find online. But nothing seems to work at all.
Here is my app.yml files:

```
runtime: custom

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 app.wsgi
env: flex 

# any environment variables you want to pass to your application.
# accessible through os.environ['VARIABLE_NAME']
env_variables:
 ... 
  
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: site:asia-northeast2:site-db

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
manual_scaling: 
  instances: 1

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

And Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
#FROM python:3.7
#FROM python:3.8.0-slim-buster

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install GDAL dependencies
#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes libgdal-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --reinstall -y \
  #libopenjp2-7 \
  #libopenjp2-7-dev \
  #libgdal-dev \
  binutils \
  gdal-bin \
  python-gdal \
  python3-gdal 


# Update C env vars so compiler can find gdal
#ENV CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
#ENV C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.
# Use -p python3 or -p python3.7 to select python version. Default is version 2.
RUN virtualenv /env -p python3

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app

# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 main:app --timeout 0 --preload
```

Someone help me here. What is it I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

While doing some research on it, it seems like the error is because the gdal library have a variable OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64 which was introduced in v. 2.0.0 [1] and it seems that you are using Python 3.7 and for this library you need Python 3.8 version.

There could be 2 possible causes of your issue:

1. The python image which is not the latest
2. The library python-gdal

To solve your issue, could you please replace the image "gcr.io/google-appengine/python" to the following :

- gcr.io/google-appengine/python:latest

And to also install the library python3-gdal instead of python-dgal as following:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y binutils gdal-bin python3-gdal
```

[1] https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/e5371b782e78f417cf0c9e551e381434ef1c9b73#diff-86e53c6a1e95018240ee21c6b8ce6832R361